# How to solve looping of multiple-line reading while breaking Scanner in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, multiline

Im trying to read multiple lines from console. I don't know the number of lines and it may differ. I know only that each line contains 2 numbers and space between them. But when I try to read them, scanner always expects a new line after I break it. I tried using `.hasNextLine()` and `if (line.isEmpty())` conditions and other variants that I had found, but always had the same result. Part of code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
HashMap<Integer, Integer> numberPairs = new HashMap<>();
String line;
while(s.hasNextLine()) {
    line = s.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
       break;
    } else {
       int[] numbers = parseLine(line);
       if (numbers != null) {
           numberPairs.put(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
       }
    }
}
```

Though, it was working when code was looking this way (but it was processing only second line from 2 lines I had entered):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
HashMap<Integer, Integer> numberPairs = new HashMap<>();
while(s.hasNextLine()) {
    if (s.nextLine().isEmpty()) {
       break;
    } else {
       int[] numbers = parseLine(s.nextLine());
       if (numbers != null) {
           numberPairs.put(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
       }
    }
}
```

Where could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: `nextLine()` consumes a line from the input. Your second example consumes 2 lines: one for the empty check, one for the actual parsing. What's the problem with your first snippet?

Comment: I figured it and used variable ```line``` to save current line, but scanner started to expect new line again. I cant stop it from reading new lines. But in second code it wasnt asking for a new line

Comment: ```if (line.isEmpty())``` had to solve this problem, as other responds offer, but it doesn't for my case.

Comment: In few words, part
```if (line.isEmpty()) {break;}```
is not working when it should

Comment: don't you want `continue` instead of `break`?

Comment: tried now, same result

Comment: Shouldn't this supposed to be `numberPairs.put(numbers[0], numbers[1]);`? "scanner always expects a new line" -- That is how Scanner works.

Comment: fair point, overlooked this one. Changed to 0 and 1, thanks. And yes, but I try to break it on empty line, but it is not breaking. Changed title of question, hope it is more clear now

Comment: It does break when I tested the first example. I think you want `hasNext()` rather than `hasNextLine()`. `hasNextLine` will include empty lines as well.

Comment: I just tried with ```hasNext()```, entered two lines, pressed enter, and it had to break the scan, but it didnt break it, just left empty lines.

Comment: How can you entered two lines and pressed enter? Each line is separated by an enter. ***"it had to break the scan"*** -- Of course not. You're checking for empty line which is the ***next*** line.

Comment: Does it work same with hasNext()? Shall it count empty line as next token too? If yes, how can I break the input then? I tried to break it using check on empty line. Oh and, meant I have entered 2 lines, separated by enter, and after next enter was empty line and I expected it to break the scan, as on empty line it had to break, as I setted it in my code

Comment: `hasNext()` != `hasNextLine()`. Why don't you just use `System.out.println()`? Print anything you like or think necessary. This way, you'll understand your code better.

Comment: Thank you for advice, I use it when I need to check smth. And now with that condition you gave and putting few more ```System.out.println()```, I see it doesnt read single line, and when I enter 2 lines, it starts working with first line. I guess we better move it chat then?